# Rails caches_action and Dynamic HTML Meta Tags in Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using caches_action in a controller:

```
 class HomeController < ApplicationController
   caches_action :index, :layout => false, :expires_in => 20.minutes
```

And in the layout (application.erb) I have the following meta tags:

```
<title><%= @title %> on MySite.com</title>
<meta name="description" content="<%= @description %>">
<!-- Add the following three tags inside head -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="<%= @title %> on MySite.com">
<meta itemprop="description" content="<%= @description %>">
```

In the Home Controller I have the following:

```
def index
  @title = "This is an example title"
  @description = "This is an example description"
```

However the cached page that is shown does not have the @title nor @description filled in for the outputted HTML.  I really like caches_action does everything I want except for dynamic meta tags in the application.erb file (layout).

How can I update the meta tags while using caches_action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I was able to get this to work was the following:

In the home view for (eg index.erb) I have the following:

```
<% content_for :seotitle do %>
<title><%=raw @seotitle %></title>
<% end %>
<% content_for :seodescription do %>
<meta name="description" content="<%=raw @seodescription %>">
<% end %>
```

In my application.erb layout I have the following:

```
<%=raw yield :seotitle %>
<%=raw yield :seodescription %>
```

Plus I need the following custom code/hack added as an intializer in my config dir to get all the pieces working:

https://gist.github.com/dignoe/2485272

Answer (score 1):

Did You try using `<% provide(:title, "This is an example title") %>` in `index.html.erb`(in the view) and `<title><%= yield(:title) %> on MySite.com</title>` in layout? In this case passing `:layout => false` to caches_action could help.

Comment: Hi Ivan - I tried your suggestion on the :title tag and it didn't print out the the @title var (It was blank).  So far the only thing that works is a before_filter method in the controller to determine the title and description but I would prefer this in the view like your example....

Comment: @Ranknoodle my suggestion had nothing to do with @title var. `provide` defines a block, which you then reuse in layout via `yield(:title)`

Comment: @IvanSelivanov Very good solution to this problem. This should be the accepted answer. Nice, clean and effective.